# Is the use of reflexive required when possible?

Tags: grammar, pronoun, reflexive

> (a) Er ist stolz auf sich selbst.

is a natural translation of "He is proud of himself."

My question is whether

> (b) Er ist stolz auf ihn selbst.

is correct or not? That is, when the sentence refers back to the person himself, and it is possible to use the reflexive **sich**, do we *have to* use it?

Comment: Er ist stolz auf sich (ohne selbst). - Er ist stolz auf ihn (zB seinen Sohn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Take the same sentences without *selbst*.</sup>

First sentence: "He is proud of himself".
Second sentence: "He is proud of him."

> sich → himself
>   ihn → him *(someone else than the subject)*

---

<sup>Add *selbst* again.</sup>

The confusing part is the similarity between `ihn selbst` and `himself`, which are **not** the same. For reflexivity, as can be seen from above, German uses *sich*. Interestingly, English doesn't seem to have an etymological pendant.

*Selbst* however, is either an adverb like in "even she", a particle meaning "self" (*selbst gemacht*), or a particle emphasizing its antecedent (He himself is responsible).

**First sentence variations with *selbst***

> Selbst der Vater ist stolz auf sich. *(Even the father is proud of himself.)*
>   Der Vater selbst ist stolz auf sich.  *(The father himself is proud of himself.)*
>   Der Vater ist stolz auf sich selbst. *(The father is proud of himself.)*

**Second sentence variations**

> Selbst der Vater ist stolz auf ihn. *(Even the father is proud of him.)*
>   Der Vater selbst ist stolz auf ihn. *(The father himself is proud of him.)*
>   Der Vater ist stolz auf ihn selbst. *(here,* selbst *does **not** refer to "father")*

Not sure if the last construction can be translated nicely. Anyway, that variation is rarely used and often ambiguous:

> Er hat sie selbst gesehen. *(*selbst *can refer to both pronouns)*

To unambiguously emphasize the object, put it in front:

> Sie selbst hat er gesehen.
>   Sie selbst wurde von ihm gesehen. *(passive)*

---

(Adressing the last paragraph) The verb you need for a certain meaning is either reflexive or not<sup>1</sup>. If it is, you have to use the corresponding reflexive pronoun:

```
Reflexivity with acc. pron.   Reflexivity with dat. pron.
ich mich        wir uns       ich mir         wir uns
du dich         ihr euch      du dir          ihr euch
er/sie/es sich  sie sich      er/sie/es sich  sie sich
```

<sup>1</sup>There are only very few cases where you can choose to leave out the pronoun (*sich flüchten*, *sich denken*).

Comment: Link: Deutsche Grammatik: Reflexiv-Pronomen http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Refl.html