# Kann "selbst" auf das Objekt einer Handlung angewandt werden?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

In [einer Antwort zu einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/16123/1224) wurde implizit erwähnt, dass das Demonstrativpronomen *selbst* auf ein Objekt (im Aktiv) angewandt werden kann.

> Der Vater ist stolz auf ihn selbst.
>   Sie selbst hat er gesehen.
>   Er hat sie selbst gesehen. (selbst can refer to both pronouns)

Spontan hätte ich gesagt, dass dies nicht möglich ist und *selbst* nur auf das Subjekt angewandt werden kann. Folglich wären die ersten beiden Beispiele falsch und das letzte eindeutig.
Für das Passiv gilt dann genau das Entgegengesetzte, da Subjekt und Objekt dort vertauscht sind. Das folgende Beispiel sehe ich demnach auch als falsch an.

> Sie selbst wurde von ihm gesehen. (passive)

Dann fiel mir aber auf, dass es sehr wohl möglich ist, *selbst* auf das grammatikalische Objekt anzuwenden. Das folgende Beispiel ist physikalisch gesehen wahrscheinlich falsch, aber grammatikalisch vollkommen richtig.

> Die Sonne lässt den Mond selbst strahlen.

Das Besondere hier ist, dass der Mond selbst wiederum eine Handlung ausführt: Er leuchtet.

Im folgenden Satz hingegen kann *selbst* nur Bezug auf die Sonne nehmen.

> Die Sonne bestrahlt den Mond selbst.

Wenn ich nun also im Titel von "Objekt einer Handlung" spreche, meine ich nicht das grammatikalische Objekt des Satzes. Im Satz "Die Sonne lässt den Mond selbst strahlen." ist *Mond* zwar das grammatikalische Objekt, fungiert aber gleichzeitig auch als Subjekt einer Handlung. Insofern ist es für mich in Ordnung, *selbst* dem Mond zuzuordnen.
In dem Satz "Die Sonne bestrahlt den Mond selbst." führt der Mond keine Handlung aus, ist somit in jeglicher Hinsicht das Objekt. Daher kann *selbst* meiner Ansicht nach nur der Sonne zugeordnet werden.

Auch erwähnen möchte ich folgendes Beispiel

> ein selbst genähtes Kleid

Ein Unterschied fällt sofort auf. *Selbst* steht vor dem Nomen, nicht dahinter. Und der Satz entspricht einer verkürzten Form von: "Ein Kleid, das ich selbst genäht habe." oder "Ein Kleid, das von mir selbst genäht wurde."
Während die Nominalphrase "ein selbst genähtes Kleid" durchaus Subjekt des Satzes sein kann, nimmt *selbst* in Wirklichkeit aber einen Bezug auf das nicht explizit genannte Subjekt der Handlung *nähen*.

Damit bleibe ich weiterhin der Meinung, dass die eingangs erwähnten Beispiele falsch sind. 
Liege ich hier richtig?<sup>1</sup> Oder wie seht ihr das? Kann *selbst* Bezug auf das Objekt einer Handlung nehmen?

---

<sup>1</sup>Es ist mir klar, dass eine Frage nach richtig oder falsch an und für sich nicht ganz elegant ist. Etwas, was heute als falsch angesehen wird und trotzdem von hunderten von Menschen verwendet wird, wird irgendwann 'richtig' sein.
Außerdem würde selbst ich bei Bedarf *selbst* auf das pure Objekt anwenden, wenn es für Betonung oder so notwendig ist – in der Umgangssprache einzig, versteht sich.
Daher eliminiere ich für meine Frage jegliche situationsnotwendigen Anwendungen in informellen Sprachregistern.

Anmerkung: Wie von vielen angemerkt, kann "selbst" natürlich auch als Partikel oder Adverb verwendet werden, doch um diese Verwendung geht es mir hier nicht, da es eben eine vollkommen andere Funktion ausübt.

Comment: Das Sonne-Mond-Beispiel strapaziert das Hirn schon arg, weil die physikalische Aussage falsch ist und zum Widerspruch reizt. Aber man kann ja analoge Beispiele konstruieren, die nicht unter dem Problem leiden: "Oma schenkte Lydia 8 Euro für das Technikmuseum. Als Mutter mit Lydia in die Ausstellung 'Ottomotoren gestern und heute' ging, ließ sie diese daher selbst bezahlen, spendierte aber ein gemischtes Eis mit Sahne hinterher." Hier ist die Mutter das Subjekt, aber Lydia ein Sub-Subjekt.

Comment: In den ersten Beispielen ist es schwierig, weil das 'selbst' hierhin oder dahin gehören könnte. In den Dahin-Fällen kann (und sollte?) man es aber weglassen, und der Satz verliert nichts - eher gewinnt er an Klarheit. Aber mit entsprechendem Kontext sind Ausnahmen konstruierbar. "Eva ging zum Elvis-Ähnlichkeitswettbewerb und sah ihn selbst dort." Der Satz chargiert jedoch, und mit mehr Kontext gewinnt er gleich wieder eine andere Bedeutung. "Eva hatte schon den ganzen Tag einen störenden, blauen Fleck im Geischtsfeld. Abends ging sie zum Elvis-...".

Comment: *selbst* ist für mich kein Demonstrativpronomen, sondern eine Partikel und auch in manchen Verwendungen ein Adjektiv in möglicherweise adverbialer Verwendung - Auch wenn sich die Geister da scheiden.

Answer (score 2):

Je länger ich drüber nachdenke, desto mehr komme ich zum Schluss, dass sich "selbst" (übrigens *kein* Demonstrativpronomen) selten auf das Subjekt bezieht - dann in der Bedeutung "sogar" (vorangestellt) oder "höchstpersönlich" (nachgestellt). 
Meistens bezieht es sich auf das Objekt, das meistens vom Reflexivpronomen "sich" gebildet wird - dann als Hervorhebung des Rückbezugs (nachgestellt) oder wiederum als Ersatz für "sogar" (vorangestellt).
Die Seltenheit bzw. Häufigkeit dieser Fälle hängen wohl damit zusammen, dass es für den rückbezüglichen Einsatz keine Alternativen gibt - für die anderen Möglichkeiten schon.

Die in der Frage genannten Beispiele klingen meiner Meinung nach darum seltsam, weil sie ohne Kontext stehen. Wenn man einen solchen Kontext konstruiert, klingen sie plötzlich komplett einleuchtend:

> Seine Mutter ist wahnsinnig stolz auf die Familie ihres Sohnes, vor
>   allem seine Kinder.
>   Sein Vater [dagegen] ist stolz auf ihn selbst.

Comment: Ich habe bewusst die Frage auf die Anwendung als Demonstrativpronomen eingeschränkt. Ja, "selbst" kann auch als Adverb oder Partikel verwendet werden, aber genau um die Fälle geht es mir nicht. Zugeben, es ist häufig schwierig (für mich zumindest) eine klare Abgrenzung zu ziehen, wann es welche Funktion einnimmt; aber die Verwendung von "sogar" und "persönlich" wollte ich in meiner Frage nicht miteinbeziehen. Ich werde das noch ergänzen.

Comment: Trotzalledem gebe ich dir Recht, dass der Kontext hier eine sehr wichtige Rolle spielt. Die Beispiele wirken auf einmal richtig. Das muss ich mir nochmal genauer anschauen ;)

Comment: @Em1 (1. Kommentar): Ah, ok - wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, geht es Dir ausschließlich um die reflexive Verwendung (auch hier kein Pronomen, aber egal :)) -- Dann bleibt eigentlich *nur* die Verwendung mit dem Objekt, weil beim Subjektbezug soweit ich sehe, immer "sogar" bzw. "persönlich" verstanden wird... Reflexiv wird es eigentlich nur im Zusammenhang mit dem Reflexivpronomen "sich" (das sozusagen das Objekt bildet) verstanden - und auch da nur in nachgestellter Position.

Comment: Naja, ich seh das so, dass es in "Ich selbst" ein Demonstrativpronomen ist, weil ich–sozusagen–auf mich selbst 'zeige'. Es bedeutet nich unbedingt "persönlich" und als Apposition schon mal gar nicht "sogar". DWDS, Wiktionary und Grimm definieren "selbst" als Pronomen, daher denke ich auf der sicheren Seite zu sein.

Comment: @Em1: Nee, schon klar: "sogar" heißt es nur beim Einsatz als vorangestelltes Adverb. Aber "ich selbst" kann man tatsächlich als Pronomen auffassen - ich habe nur ein Problem damit, "selbst" als solches zu bezeichnen. Es hat mit den echten Pronomen absolut nichts gemeinsam. Der einzige Bezug ist, dass es bei den echten Pronomen stehen kann und diese einfärbt.

Comment: Hm, guter Punkt. Im Englischen heißt es ja auch "myself" ("I did it myself" und nicht "I did it self"). Im Englischen heißt es aber auch "I am proud of him" und niemals "I am proud of himself". Und mal angenommen "Ich bin stolz auf ihn selbst" wäre richtiges und gutes Deutsch, so versage ich doch, eine Übersetzung zu finden, die das "selbst" wiederspiegelt. Daraus komm ich zu dem Punkt, dass es mit Sicherheit im Deutschen zumindest *historisch gesehen* falsch ist. Bleibt die Frage, wie es mit dem 'heutigen' Deutsch aussieht.

Comment: @Em1: Bin mir nicht sicher, ob der Vergleich mit dem Englischen auf einen grünen Zweig führt... Die im Deutschen möglichen beiden Abstufungen "sich" und "sich selbst" gibt's da schlichtweg nicht in dieser Form. Was in die Richtung ginge wäre vielleicht sowas wie "he himself" - in Deinem Beispiel (das ich wieder im in meiner Antwort konstruierten Kontext sehe) wäre u.U. "I am proud of him himself" denkbar.

Comment: @Em1 Der Vergleich vermischt Etymologie und erlangte Funktion, eine unmittelbare Konsequenz wäre die Übersetzung von "He himself said that" als "Er ihn selbst sagte das". Um einen fruchtbaren Vergleich zu ziehen, müsste man sich zusätzlich die englische Etymologie zu Gemüte führen. Das sagt dann aber immer noch nichts über den heutigen Gebrauch im Deutschen aus. Bei reflexiven Verben kann "himself" zB *nur* mit "sich" übersetzt werden... himself != er selbst = he himself.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Selbst* kann **kein** Pronomen sein (lat. *pro*, für, anstelle von):</sub>

> <sup>Dieser verschwand unbemerkt. | Selbst verschwand unbemerkt.
>
>   Jene Königin, die... | Selbst Königin, die...
>
>   Selbst die Opposition war einverstanden. | (beliebiges Pronomen) die Opposition war einverstanden.
>
>   *(incorrect versions after |)*</sup>

Sieht man sich die verschiedenen Verwendungsmöglichkeiten unten an, fällt eine Gemeinsamkeit auf: Hervorhebung eines bestimmten Aspekts.

Fehlt nun der Kontext, gibt es auch keine Aspekte, die man betonen bzw. abgrenzen könnte. Überdies sind die Beispiele nur Mittel zum Zweck - grammatikalische Schablonen.
Mac hat schon eine großartige Verwendungsmöglichkeit präsentiert.

> Er hat sie selbst gesehen.

ist zweideutig, weil sich *selbst* auch auf das Verb beziehen kann, was eine Zugehörigkeit zum Subjekt impliziert. Unten habe ich versucht zu zeigen, dass sich *selbst* auch auf Nomen beziehen kann, die nicht im 1. Fall stehen.

---

- im Sinne von *sogar*, als Fokuspartikel:

  > Selbst die Königin haben wir getroffen.
- drückt in Verbindung mit Verben aus, dass außer dem Agens sonst niemand beteiligt war, Adverb:

  > selbst gemachter Kuchen
  >   Ich habe es selbst gesehen! *(mit "selbst" nach "Ich" eher iSv. "höchstpersönlich")*
  >   sich selbst die Zähne putzen *(zur Probe ersetze man mit "heute" oder dgl.)*
- zur Betonung/Hervorhebung eines Bezugswortes, welches nicht im 1. Fall stehen muss:

  > Sie selbst möchte das. *(Ihre Eltern zwingen sie nicht dazu)*
  >   Es ist der Wunsch ihrer selbst. *(wie oben)*
  >   Ihr selbst genügt es. *(Bei anderen Menschen wäre dies nicht so)*
  >   Es interessiert ihn selbst auch. *(Er macht nicht nur wegen ihr mit)*

  durch Negation → Abgrenzung/Entgegenstellung:

  > Die Königin selbst haben wir nicht getroffen. *(nur ihren Sohn, den Prinzen)*
- im Sinne von *(höchst)persönlich*:

  > Die Königin selbst haben wir getroffen.

Comment: Lustig, dass jeder, der sich hier beteiligt hat, sagt, dass "selbst" kein Pronomen ist, interesannterweise aber einzig der Duden es nicht als Pronomen deklariert. DWDS und Grimm und noch einige weitere Seiten sagen, dass es ein Pronomen ist. Wiktionary und [Canoo](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr-selbst.html) deklarieren es explizit als Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: @Em1 Was ist meiner Widerlegung entgegenzusetzen? Was ist  diesen Seiten zufolge denn ein Pronomen? Im online-Duden wird es als Partikel bezeichnet. Und cannoo schummelt eine adverbiale Verwendung als Beispiel durch.

Comment: Muss "pro" die Bedeutung "anstelle" haben? Kann es nich einfach "für" heißen? ("für" bedeutet nicht zwingend 'ersetzen')

Comment: @Em1 Kann es, es könnte aber genauso gut Latein für "Ente" sein. Die Information war als Trivia gedacht. Es geht darum, dass ein Pronomen per definitionem stellvertretend für ein *Nomen* sein können **muss** (was praktischerweise mit dem dazugehörigen Latein einhergeht). *Selbst* kann dies nun mal nicht - wie man aus den anfänglichen Beispielen nicht deutlicher sehen könnte - und ist damit auch kein Pronomen. Jedes andere Pronomen schafft diesen Test mit links.

Comment: Naja nicht ganz jedes: KNG muss natürlich passen und Reflexivpronomen sind ausgenommen.

Comment: Und warum darf ein Reflexivpronomen eine Ausnahme sein, und "selbst" nicht?

Comment: Ich glaube, dann werden wir wohl auf keinen Nenner kommen, denn "selbst" hat für mich etwas 'demonstratives' und wenn Reflexivpronomen sich durchschummeln dürfen, weil die 'reflexive Bedingung' gegeben ist (und sie ersetzen insofern schon, weil sie eine Wiederholung vermeiden: "Karl schaut Karl im Spiegel an.), dann ist "selbst" auch ein Demonstrativpronomen, denn es erspart uns auch die Wiederholung ("Die Königin, Die Königin habe ich nicht gesehen).

Comment: @Em1 Reflexivpronomen sind Personalpronomen des Nominativs (und auch Genitivs?) beraubt wurden. Nimmt man also ein auf KNG abgestimmtes Personalpronomen, passt alles wieder. Damit sind Reflexivpronomen immer noch Pronomen und *selbst* immer noch keins. Deinem *Gefühl* nach wäre dann auch *heute* ein Pronomen.

Comment: @Em1 Falsch, denn eine technisch richtige Ersetzung würde zu einem sinnlosen Beistrich bzw. zu einem grammatikalisch falschen Satz führen: Die Königin, selbst habe ich nicht gesehen.

Comment: OK, eine weitere Diskussion ergibt keinen Sinn. Du hast deine Argumente angebracht, ich meine. Wir sind uns da nicht einig und werden uns auch nicht einig. Zumal das ganze überhaupt nicht Kernpunkt meiner Frage war. Danke für deine Bemühungen all the same.

Comment: @Em1 Die *Definition* von Pronomen zu ignorieren ist ziemlich ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

Die Beispiele

> Der Vater ist stolz auf ihn selbst. 
>   Sie selbst hat er gesehen.

sehen für mich merkwürdig aus, und ich würde "selbst" so nicht verwenden. Trotzdem kann man "selbst" auf Objekte anwenden, allerdings ist es dann nicht reflexiv:

> Ihn selbst habe ich auf der Party nicht gesehen, aber ich habe gehört, dass er da war. 
>   Ihm selbst konnte ich die Ware nicht geben, aber ich habe sie ihm durch einen Dritten zukommen lassen.

Die Bedeutung ist dann "in Person". In ähnlicher Weise geht es mit der Bedeutung "sogar":

> Selbst ihm kann man so etwas nicht zumuten. 
>   Selbst ihn kann ich nicht verstehen, wenn er nicht laut genug redet.

Beide Bedeutungen halte ich auch für schriftsprachlich möglich.

Comment: Ich finde nicht, dass die Beispiele den Kern der Frage treffen. Wie wäre es mit folgendem? "Ihn selbst habe ich auf der Party nicht gesehen, aber seinen Assistenten."  Ich gebe zu, dass sich das nicht nach einer tollen Party anhört.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz und dirkt: Der Satz "Ich habe nicht ihn selbst gesehen, ..." ist für mich in der Tat absolut in Ordnung. Ich frage mich gerade, was der Unterschied ist. Es handelt sich glaube ich immer noch um ein Demonstrativpronomen. Warum handelt es sich dann um 'gutes' Deutsch, während es in "Der Vater ist stolz auf ihn selbst" eher 'schlechtes' Deutsch ist?

Comment: @Em1: Für mich ergibt "ist stolz auf ihn selbst" inhaltlich keinen Sinn, genauso wenig wie "ist stolz auf ihn in Person". Die Bedeutung passt einfach nicht. Und bei "sich selbst" ist die Bedeutung eine etwas andere, da ist der hinweisende/verstärkende Charakter eher im Vordergrund, nicht "sich in Person".

Comment: Wie wäre „der Vater ist Stolz auf ihn selbst und nicht auf seine Berühmtheit“? Zugegeben, das ist etwas holprig.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Hm, durchaus in Ordnung. Es entspricht hier einer Art Hervorhebung, dass es um die Person selbst geht und eben nicht um etwas anderes. Interessant. Entkräftigt jetzt natürlich komplett meine These :D

Answer (score 0):

So, wie man altmodisch die Phrase "höchstselbst" für "höchstpersönlich" verwendet, kann man "selbst" für eine abgeschwächtere Form "persönlich" benutzen. Unter Umständen kann damit aber auch ausgedrückt werden - analog zu persönlich - , dass die entsprechende person es (was auch immer "es" ist) selbst mitgeteilt hat und nicht etwa über Dritte.

Comment: "Selbst" im Sinne von "persönlich" kann auf das Subjekt angewandt werden("Ich selbst habe es ihm nicht gesagt"). Weder widerlegst du meine These damit, noch bestätigst du sie. Dank der Antwort von dirkt ist mir jetzt aber bewusst, dass man auch "Ich habe es nicht ihm selbst gesagt" sagen kann, was in der Tat zweideutig ist: "nicht ich, sondern wer anders" oder "nicht ihm, sondern wem anders". Warum funktionert das, aber nicht "Der Vater ist stolz auf ihn selbst". Wo ist der Unterschied? Hängt doch nicht vom Subjekt ab, sondern muss eine andere Bedingung erfüllt sein? Nimmt das Verb Einfluss?

Comment: @Em1: Superinteressante Frage! Allerdings hat dieses Beispiel "ich habe es nicht ihm selbst gesagt" absolut eindeutig die zweite genannte Bedeutung. "nicht ich,..." wäre: "Ich habe es ihm nicht selbst gesagt." Einmal bildet "ihm selbst" eine Phrase, einmal "ich selbst" (evtl. könnte man hier auch für "selbst sagen" argumentieren...).

Comment: @Mac Fair enough. Das stimmt. Hilft mir nur nicht weiter zu verstehen, warum "ihm selbst" vereinzelnd akzeptabel ist, oft aber auch nicht.

Comment: Durch die Flexibilität des Satzbaus ist zwar "Ich habe es nicht ihm selbst(=er) gesagt" eindeutig etwas anderes als "Ich habe es ihm nicht selbst(=ich) gesagt", aber ohne Negation könnte "ich habe es ihm selbst gesagt" beides sein - verstanden wird hierbei wohl fast durchweg selbst=Subjekt. Man würde für den (unverneinten) Bezug aufs Objekt eher "direkt/unmittelbar" (oder in anderen Konstruktionen "eigentlich" (attributiv) statt "selbst" verwenden)